# Multiple click functionality on link in Angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a link that triggers a modal to appear, but also need to apply a class to the `body` in order to set `position: fixed` due to the iOS 11 bootstrap modal form field bug. However, this isn't setting the property to the body.

**HTML**

```
<body class="" ng-class="{'login-form' : toggle, 'login-form' : !toggle}" window-detection page-class>

<a ng-click="openLoginModal(); toggle = !toggle"
   data-rt-id="login--sm">[[ "Login / Join" | translate ]]</a>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
   @media screen and (max-width: 414px){
    .login-form{
     position: fixed!important;
   }
}
```

How can I toggle a class on the body when the user clicks the login button?

Comment: Use `ng-class` ....

Comment: The body class wasn't showing in the original post, fixed the question.

Comment: So is the link in same scope as the body with no child scopes or isolated scopes in between?

Comment: The link with `openLoginModal()` is in a `HeaderController` controller.

Comment: Then `toggle` as a primitive is only in that scope. Could add it to $rootScope and then would be seen on body tag

Answer (score 0):

Which bootstrap version are you using . Use 3.2 version.
You can use some thing like that
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
margin-top:70px
}

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like so.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

});
```

```css
.login-form{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body class="" ng-class="{'login-form' : toggle, '' : !toggle}" window-detection page-class ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">

<a ng-click="openLoginModal(); toggle = !toggle"
   data-rt-id="login--sm">{{"Login / Join" }}</a>
</body>
```